# Update query not throwing error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

Thanks for the help in advance.

Im trying to use update query in C#

> Error : command is getting executed even if I use incorrect values

[Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCTkL.png)
Code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("update Comcast_AvayaID set Status='Inactive' where Employee_Id='" + TxtEMPID.Text + "' and AvayaID ='" + TxtAvayaID.Text + "'", con);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Avaya_Id SET Status = 'UnAssigned' where Avaya_ID ='" + TxtAvayaID.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        LBLSuccess.Visible = true;
        LBLSuccess.Text = "Deactivation Successfull";
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        LBLSuccess.Visible = true;
        LBLSuccess.Text = "Deactivation Unsuccessfull";
    }
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Use parameterized queries!

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect values`? Are you wanting to add input validation?

Comment: Instead of writing an useless message when you get the exception write out the _ex.Message_ property. This will be necessary to understand what happens here (and of course tell us what do you get there)

Comment: Why do you want to transfer message you don't about to user? @Steve Don't do what previous comment says. SqlException can be anything about, user not for sure supposed to see it, and if you show it it can be +1 to threat

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy we are trying to debug its problem. Better if he could write the exception in a log file but for the purpose to understand what's happening then let the exception be visible. In a production code you don't have the exception handler at all if you don't plan to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code would look better like this, it not the most optimal, but ia already a way better piece of code then your snippet

1) added parameters using a helper function for the sql injection issue

2) an ExecuteNonQuery returns the rows affected, so if you are expecting that 1 row was updated, you can check on that

3) if you update a row with an id that not exists, it will not throw a SqlException like you are expecting in your code, this happens e.g. when locking occurs

```
 public void Update()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {

                var empId = TxtEMPID.Text
                var avayaId = TxtAvayaID.Text
                con.Open();

                var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Comcast_AvayaID set Status='Inactive' where Employee_Id=@empId and AvayaID = @avayaId", con);              
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(AddParameter("@empId",empId));
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(AddParameter("@avayaId", avayaId));

                var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Avaya_Id SET Status = 'UnAssigned' where Avaya_ID =avayaId", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(AddParameter("@avayaId", avayaId));

                var rowsaffected1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var rowsAffected2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsaffected1 == 1 && rowsAffected2 == 1)
                {
                    //success code goes here
                    //--------
                    LBLSuccess.Visible = true;
                    LBLSuccess.Text = "Deactivation Successfull";
                }
                else
                {
                    // failure code goes here
                    //-----------------------
                    LBLSuccess.Visible = true;
                    LBLSuccess.Text = "Deactivation Unsuccessfull";
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //handle errors
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private SqlParameter AddParameter(string name, object value) {
            var par = new SqlParameter();
            par.ParameterName = name;
            par.Value = value;
            return par;
        }
```

Comment: The solution worked great. But why this function is used  private SqlParameter AddParameter(string name, object value) {
            var par = new SqlParameter();
            par.ParameterName = name;
            par.Value = value;
            return par;
        }

Comment: it is just a helper function since there is no default constructor to create a SqlParameter with name and value. By using this you will you cleaner code and less repeats. And i use the parameters to prevent SQL injection in your queries like your sample was doing see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection for more info on sql injection

Comment: @BenCroughs we have [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) from ages now. However, when adding a parameter, it always good practice to specify its type and size.

Comment: @Steve thx forgot about that one, i am still old school sometimes :-) but indeed with the helper function you can easily add type and size

Comment: Why did you put catch(SqlException) - which exceptions do you expect here?

Comment: If you write no code inside catch - better remove this catch and use using construction

Comment: @BenCroughs , The code is working Fine. The If Condition is not working. It loops if we enter wrong data. It doesnt throw error

Comment: what do you mean with wrong data ? and the if only checks how many rows affected, it will never throw an exception, if you want one, you must throw an exception in the else of the if

Comment: @BenCroughs The If section is not working. It Loops for long time. Nothing is displayed even if the update command executes

Answer (score 0):

If you put "incorrect" values it just updates zero of records. No errors/exception expected here.